# Fetching two matches in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have some code I'm trying to figure out... I have two tables:

TABLE: matches

```
event_id
match_id (primary)
match_score
match_p1
match_p2
match_win
```

TABLE: results

```
event_id
user_id
result_id (primary)
result_name
result_extra
```

The weird thing about the data is the content of of the matches table actually links to the results table in multiple fashions.

There will be an integer in `match_p1` and `match_p2` that link to the `results_extra` field on the results table. This is designed because each match has two players in it (p1 and p2), and each player has one result for each event.

If I wanted to get a list of all matches in an event, I would do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM matches
WHERE event_id = 324
```

If I wanted to get a list of all matches belonging to a single player, I would do:

```
SELECT matches.*
FROM matches
    LEFT JOIN results
        ON ((results.result_extra = matches.match_p1) OR
            (results.result_extra = matches.match_p2))
WHERE results.user_id = 1566
```

However, this is where things get a bit complicated... What if I wanted to get a list of matches where player `1566` fought player `2058`? Its the logic for this query I can't figure out. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain the data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. Join `results` twice, and match the 2 player combinations.

```
select a.*
from matches a
join results b on a.match_p1 = b.result_extra
join results c on a.match_p2 = c.result_extra
where (b.user_id = 1566 and c.user_id = 2058) or (b.user_id = 2058 and c.user_id = 1566)
```

Comment: Thats a really smart and simple answer! Wow... never thought of this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could be this

```
SELECT matches.*
FROM matches
LEFT JOIN results a
    ON ((a.result_extra = matches.match_p1  AND
         a.result_extra = matches.match_p2))
LEFT JOIN results b
    ON ((b.result_extra = matches.match_p1 AND
         b.result_extra = matches.match_p2))      
WHERE a.user_id = 2058
AND b.user_id = 1566
```

Comment: user IDs are not in the match table... if they were, this would be simple.

Comment: then explain better  1566  and 2058 what are ?

Comment: There are in the `results` table... Its shown in the last query I posted `WHERE results.user_id = 1566`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Your answer, just like @Fabricator's seems to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If 1566 and 2059 is user_ids,maybe this help you

```
SELECT matches.*
FROM matches
    LEFT JOIN results
        ON ((results.result_extra = matches.match_p1) OR
            (results.result_extra = matches.match_p2))
WHERE results.user_id in (1566,2058);
```

Comment: That would match if EITHER player is in a match... not if BOTH players are in the match.